# Datagrip: Auto formatting SQL keywords in console

Tags: datagrip

In Datagrip, I would like to be able to auto format my SQL queries while I'm typing, similar to what you can do in Sequel Pro or TablePlus.

For example, with my current setup with Sequel Pro, typing `select` and pressing space will automatically change it to `SELECT`, and this is the same for any SQL keyword.

For Datagrip, I have tried every setting in the `Code Style -> SQL` preferences, but no matter what I try it does not format any SQL automatically in a Console, nor does it add any indentation. My settings look like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfK4C.png)

Is this just not possible in Datagrip, and am I interpreting the settings wrong? I appreciate that `CMD-OPT-L` does format the code after you've written it but it's not quite right for my use case.

Comment: If you chose SELECT from the code completion list, it will be capitalized according to settings.

Comment: Thanks, though is there a way to set it to capitalise keywords without using the autocomplete? Most of the time I am typing out rather than tabbing my way through keywords

Comment: There is no such a feature at the moment. @Daf could file a new feature request in [DataGrip YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE)?

Answer (score 1):

DataGrip doesn't support formatting on the fly.

It requires explicit format via *Reformat Code* action.